# Python- no module named error. wherever i place the __init__.py file the ingestor file just cant seem to get at it

Tags: python, flask

```
project structure


__init__.py
backend

      __init__.py

      /log_parser.py

      /ingestor

      /data_aggregation

configuration

scripts

    __init__.py(holding create_app and db)

UI

utils

    /__init__.py

    /models
```

inside of the log parser is this import

`from ingestor import Ingestor`

however whenever the ingestor file gets to here

`from scripts import create_app, db` it fails with the error message

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'
(venv)

ive tried changing the directory the **init**.py file is in with no luck. I've also tried importing everything within a directory which also failed. so i'm out of ideas?

Comment: Does the root folder contain a `__init__.py` file? Otherwise it's not considered a `package` and is instead considered a folder containing `packages`.

Comment: yes it does.  apologies ive change the structure to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

If with "/" you mean that the `__init__.py` and ingestor ar on the same folder. Make sure that inside this one (ingestor folder) there is outher `__init__.py` file and try again.

If yes but always facing the same problem, try with a relative import like this: `from .ingestor import Ingestor`. Don't miss the "dot" before "ingestor"

If it doesn't work try this last one:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(".")
from ingestor import Ingestor
```

Comment: sorry I think my post is a little confusing the ingestor import works  but inside the ingestor file is this import ```from scripts import create_app, db``` which is what is failing

Comment: @JordanBailey, in this case try to do the last solution but with this modification:
`sys.path.append("project/path")` and import your desire module after that